# Look into native libraries with DDMS

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, ddms

I am trying to debug a complete halt error in the code inside a pure C++/OGL library that makes the GLRender thread stop completely. The usual tool for this is the DDMS and check where the thread is stopped at, but it seems unable to read the threads once inside the native library.

Is there any other way or tool I may be overlooking?

Comment: You need to use the ndk-gdb, rather than DDMS for native debugging.  You may find though that it's faster to identify your problem by cleve r application of native calls to the Android logging functions.

Comment: I already have ndk-gdb available but the thread doesn't seem to stop, and a manual pause ends up in SEGFAULT after trying to reach the code.

Comment: In the end ndk-gdb did the trick. In the android debug view pause the gdb threadpool and look for the one actually running the code.

Comment: @EfEs You can add your solution as an answer to this question and accept it.